# javascript link window open without extra slash

Tags: javascript

Let's say I am currently at the following link:
`"localhost/admin/test"` when i do

```
window.open("/user/list/2034", "_blank")
```

it will appear like this:

```
localhost/admin/test/user/list/2034
```

what can i do to make it like this instead?

```
  localhost/user/list/2034
```

Comment: I don't know `windows`. Do you mean `window`?

Comment: window.open("localhost/user/list/2034", _blank)
try to add a full url

Comment: Why dont you use `localhost/user/list/2034` ?

Comment: Forget `windows` @OmarMuscatello!  What's the `_blank` for? haha

Comment: *"it will appear like this: `localhost/admin/test/user/list/2034`"* No, it won't, unless the server does a redirect. The leading `/` on the relative URL makes it relative to the domain, port, and protocol only. From `http://localhost/any/path/here/at/all`, the relative link `/user/list/2034` makes the absolute URL `http://localhost/user/list/2034`.

Comment: Side note: You probably meant `_blank` to be in quotes (unless you have a variable called `_blank`). Which makes me think this isn't a copy-and-paste of your real code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - or just don't use it, it opens a new window anyway.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `windows` should be `window`.  If it really is `windows` then you have a custom object and need to show us what that is before we can answer your question.

The other point to note is that `window.open` will open a new window, regardless what you name it, so you don't need to use the `_blank` name.  You only need to specify a name if you want to subsequently reuse that window (e.g. open another URL in the same other window).

When at `http://localhost/admin/test`, if you do:

```
window.open("/user/list/2034")
```

It will go to `http://localhost/user/list/2034`, unless...

- `window.open` has been redefined somewhere.  You can do `console.log(window.open)` and the console should say something like `ƒ open() { [native code] }` if it hasn't been redefined.
- Your web server is responding to `/user/list/2034` with a redirect to `/admin/test/user/list/2034`.  The network tab in your developer console will show you the HTTP requests and responses where you can see if the web server is redirecting.
- Your link really doesn't start with a `/` and you actually have `window.open("user/list/2034")`
- You're viewing a cached version of the page with the above error in it, the source code is fixed but the browser hasn't loaded it.  Try again in a private browsing window to see if it still happens.
- You have some browser plug-in or extension interfering with your page. Try another browser/computer without the extensions and see if it still happens.

Comment: Perfect!! You the man!! I remove extensions and open a private browsing window to fix the problem